# how to Make a function (or functions) that generate a ul with li elements for each book ID in the array using a for loop?

Tags: javascript

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>my favourite books</title>
        <script src="apps.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the books array

```
const bookTitles = [
    "the_vegetarian",
    "watership_down",
    "adventures_sherlock_holmes",
    "alchemist",
    "frankenstein",
    "city_of_thieves",
    "gone_with_the_wind",
    "to_kill_mocking_bird",
    "war_and_peace",
    "things_fall_apart"];
```

Comment: The answer is in the title, *"using a for loop"*. What's not working with the one you wrote? Would you show it to us?

Comment: Hello Kaniwar and welcome to Stack Overflow. Maybe you can have a look at [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)  For example: `'<ul>'+[1,2,3].map(item=>'<li>'+item+'</li>').join('')+'</ul>'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.createElement([name of element])` to create the dom node you want.

In this case you will be using `ul` and `li`. After building the `ul`, you can iterate through your book titles and build the list items needed. Then you would append the ul onto the body of your document.

```
function generateList() {
  const newList = document.createElement('ul');

  for (let i = 0; i < bookTitles.length; i++) {
    const book = bookTitles[i];
    newList.innerHTML += `<li>${book}</li>`; 
  }

  return newList;
}

document.body.append(generateList());
```

Comment: Thanks, it is helpful and works perfectly and  i have a question about something i didn't understand which is : newList.inneHTML += `<li>${book}</li>`; why you didn't use instead newList.inneHTML = bookTItles[i]? do you have any useful sources about that or youtube channels?

Comment: += will append and reassign instead of = which would reassign. So you would want to use += to build your list. I wrote it that way because, it's just my personal preference.

You can write newList.innerHTML += `<li>${bookTitles[i]}</li>`; However the li tag is important because you want it to be a list item instead of just text.

Comment: thank you. i made also a list of objects and now i have to change the function that i used to display the book ID's in a list to take the actual information about the book from the object and display that, how can i do that?

Comment: Look up how to access an object, you can use this source https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects to read more about it. That should be more than enough to help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the sample code below, Hope it would be helpful

```js
const bookTitles = [
    "the_vegetarian",
    "watership_down",
    "adventures_sherlock_holmes",
    "alchemist",
    "frankenstein",
    "city_of_thieves",
    "gone_with_the_wind",
    "to_kill_mocking_bird",
    "war_and_peace",
    "things_fall_apart"];
let newUl = document.createElement('ul')
bookTitles.forEach(book => {
    let listItem = document.createElement("li");
    let itemText = document.createTextNode(book);
    listItem.appendChild(itemText);
    newUl.appendChild(listItem)
})

document.body.appendChild(newUl)
```

Comment: can you explain it to me, please. it's much shorter and easier but i couldn't think about this way. any sources will be appreciated .

Comment: and the reason you used (for.each) not just (for)

Comment: for looping and forEach both have a similar effect on the array, But I prefer to use forEach for readability If you prefer something on looping recommended to use `.map() ` if nothing is returned from loop you can use `.forEach()`
Here is an explanation: 

Am looping book title array with forEach and in each loop am creating new <li /> element with text node that contains current iteration book title.